# pre & post condition usage. Why isn't the program responding to conditions

Tags: c++

```
int mult (int a, int b)
{
     if (a <= 0 || b <= 0) throw (" Your input is invalid. No zero");

     int doub = a * b;

     if (doub <= 0) throw (" Invalid value");

     cout << "\\n" << doub;

     return doub;
}

//code that gives values of num1 & num2//

try
{
    mult(num1, num2);
}

catch (int error)
{
    cerr << " Error #@#$% invalid value";
}
```

The program works fine if both values (num1, numa2) are higher than 0, but if any value is less than 0 the program fails and doesn't throw the desired message. It just shows a default error.

Is it inproper use of the pre & post condition?

Is it the throw usage? (I have some doubts in how to use it, it might be that but I don't know)

Answer (score 3):

`throw (" Your input is invalid. No zero");`  You are throwing a `char *`

`catch (int error)` But you are catching an `int`.  This is a different type from `char *` so the exception is not caught and propagates up to the default handler.

The idiomatic way to do handle this would be to `throw (std::runtime_error("Your input is invalid. No zero"));`,

and `catch (std::exception & e) { cerr << e.what(); }`

Comment: "You are throwing a `char *`" - Well, no. He is *actually* throwing a `const char[32]` that decays to a `const char*`. Nowhere is he throwing a `char*`.

Comment: Also, note that it's not essential, but probably would be nicer to catch the exception by reference to const. At least there should be no reason why it shouldn't be const…

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing exceptions of type `const char *` but catching them as type `int`.  To fix this, all you need to do is change:

```
catch (int error)
```

to:

```
catch (const char * error)
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6q0f8R9OtMVVo7YH)

Or, as QuestionC says, you can throw a `std::runtime_error` and catch that.